# Rails 5 tag helper with tag name in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionviewhelper

I am converting some older code which uses `content_tag` like this:

```
wrap_tag = 'p'
....
content_tag(wrap_tag, class: 'etc') do
  'some content'
end
```

which generates the expected

```html
<p class="etc">
Some content
</div>
```

I'd now like to update to use the `tag` syntax, but I am having troubles with this:

```
wrap_tag = 'p'
...
tag wrap_tag, class: 'etc' do
  'some content'
end
```

Trying:
`tag.wrap_tag` gives `"<wrap-tag>some content</wrap-tag>"`

Not unexpected, except that the underscore has become a hyphen.

Other variations:

- Using `tag.p` directly: `<p>some content</p>`
- Using `tag.wrap_tag`:`<wrap-tag>some content</wrap-tag>`
- Using `tag.wrap_tag.to_sym`:`<wrap-tag></wrap-tag>`
- Using `tag wrap_tag`: `<p />`
- Using `tag wrap_tag.to_sym`: `<p />`

*Note: all the examples above included the `do..content..end` block shown initially*.

Is there a way to have the tag name in a variable and include content?

Thanks

---

Trying the suggestion from [jvillian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359650/jvillian) to use `send` I find that

```
wrap_tag = 'p'
content = 'some text'
helper.tag.send(wrap_tag, content)
```

returns "some text", and generally returns the second and subsequent arguments.

---

It does seem, looking at actionview/helpers/tag_helper.rb, that the *content_tag* method checks for block_given? and *tag* doesn't.

But whyyyyyyyyy (not)
I will have to read through the PR again to find out.

Comment: I wonder if using something like `tag.send(wrap_tag, ...)` might do it? Just a stray thought.

Comment: Hmm tried a similar idea while I was setting up this question - I'll try your one right now.

Comment: I think it does - from your link: "Content can also be captured with a block, which is useful in templates"

Comment: `helper.tag.send(wrap_tag) do content end` returns nil. I will push that version a but more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that if I do:

```
@arg = :div
tag.send @arg, class: 'etc' do 
  'some content'
end
```

...then I get:

```
<div class="etc">some content</div>
```

Similarly, if I do:

```
@arg = :section
tag.send @arg, class: 'etc' do 
  'some content'
end
```

...then I get:

```
<section class="etc">some content</section>
```

If, however, I do:

```
@arg = :p
tag.send @arg, class: 'etc' do 
  'some content'
end
```

...then I get:

```
{:class=>"etc"}
```

Which, obviously, is *not what one expects*. And, seems straight-up peculiar, because:

```
tag.p class: 'etc' do 
  'some content'
end
```

...gives:

```
<p class="etc">some content</p>
```

...which is all sunshine and lolipops.

Gremlins? One can only wonder.